# How to use array.every() with only the callback and optional arg, no index

Tags: javascript, arrays

The syntax for `array.every()` is:

```
arr.every(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

I have utilised this as:

```
source.every(function(source, i, sources) { ... }
```

But I don't actually use `i` in my function, is it possible to omit it whilst still using the optional arg of `sources` which comes after it?

Comment: Annoyingly, the parameter must be specified. So people tend to use an underscore `_` to represent that the variable is not used. So it'd be `function(source, _, sources) {`

Comment: No. I use `_` (underscore)  to specify that this kind of arg is not in use.

Comment: With JS function params, only the order is important, not the name. If you want to use the `array` parameter, you need to also state `index`, even though you're not using it. However if you aren't using an existing function but an anonymous one, you can simply use the outer `sources` inside the function. In that case you only need the 1st param, `source`.

Comment: You can use `arguments[2]` but I don't think it's in any way better than just having an unused parameter

Comment: No, because javascript functions use the positioning of arguments to recognize them, removing one in the middle would distort this

Answer (score 0):

`source.every(function(source, i, sources) { ... }`
Use can use:

```
source.every(function() { 
  arguments[0] // source
  arguments[2] // sources
... 
}
```

But it looks weird. Just use an underscore `_` to perform that you ignore the index.

Comment: It goes against the PO question, she seeks to clear her code, not to obscure it !

Comment: Yes, I understand, but actually, there is no way to do that. Using the underscore is the best solution I think. It's is easy if the arg passed is an object.